# Excel: how to autofit columns on startup?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to autofit all the columns in the opening sheet which contain data? I'm looking for a solution that is not depended on modifications on a certain excel file but which works on every excel file and runs on excel startup.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an object module that will receive an **Application Event** (see more info on [Chip Pearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx)).

This is the code you have to copy-paste to the module `ThisWorkbook` of the file `PERSONAL.XLSB`:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    'Statement to show that it works
    MsgBox "Opened Workbook: " & Wb.Name
    'Statement to autofit columns
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

You could also add a loop over the workbook sheets.

Comment: I think an Class Module Application Event trapping Workbook Open will be needed so that the code is triggered for each Excel file (this is written up in the same link from Pearson's site).

Comment: I copy pasted this new Class Module and saved it into my personal.xlsb. But when I open a saved excel file nothing happens and columns are not autofitted.

Comment: did you check the link and followed the instructions given by brettj?

Comment: Yes I read it but I not sure how to implement his code in this situation.

Comment: I've edited my post. You have to put the whole code I've given in the `This Workbook` module of the `PERSONAL.XLSB` file you've created

Comment: @JMax Thanks but this is not working, it just says that I opened workbook but it does not autofit columns. Tested on Excel 2007.

Comment: I've checked the code on the "Opening part" mostly. I would say the autofit part should work (I only tested it partly). Did you try to adapt the code or change it by yourself, or even record a new one?

Comment: Yes, I removed the line "MsgBox "Opened Workbook: " & Wb.Name", but the autofit still do not work.

Comment: Did you try `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit`? Everything works fine here (Excel 2007).